# Are any non-injective activation functions used?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, activation-functions, relu, softmax

All activation functions I know of are injective, which I think makes sense.

But are there cases where non-injective activations can be useful?

Comment: Do you care about clarifying what you mean by "injective" and which activation functions do you have in mind (because maybe there's a misunderstanding)?

Comment: Injective like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function. And I don't have examples in mind. Like of course |x| or sin(x) would be possible, but I'm unsure of what would be gained when using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least [Swish](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05941), which is defined as $f(x) = x \cdot \text{sigmoid}(\beta x)$.

> ...This suggests that Swish can be loosely viewed as a smooth function
> which nonlinearly interpolates between the linear function and the
> ReLU function. The degree of interpolation can be controlled by the
> model if β is set as a trainable parameter.

There is an other paper which introduces [Growing Cosine Unit](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.12943), defined as $f(x) = x \cdot \text{cos}(x)$.

> The experiments (Table 1-3) show that use of GCU activation for
> convolutional layers and ReLU for the dense layers provides the best
> performance among all architectures considered. This is particularly
> evident on the VGG-16 network trained on the Imagenette dataset, where
> the GCU models outperform all ReLU architectures by 7+%. The models
> with GCU in the convolutional layers also converge faster during
> training as highlighted by Fig 7-8.

In their experiments this GCU performed significantly better than Swish, or any other activation function.

Comment: Hm interesting. Maybe bad question as I don't have experience with academics: On Google scholar it only shows 2 citations of this paper. Is this inaccurate, or do responses just take some time, or is this result not as important as it seems?